# Missing PowerShell Commands

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and try to learn it with video tutorials on lynda.com - Everything went fine until now.

Right now, I'm on the chapter of how you can discover commands, using `get-help`. In the video he's typing, for example, `get-help *ipaddress*` and he gets a list of around ~13 commands. When I do this, I only get 2.

I've run PowerShell as administrator and I've installed the newest version.

Why can't I see all the commands?

I've already tried to import modules, but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly does the person on the tutorial get when running the command? And what do you get?

Comment: Which Windows and Powershell versions were used in the tutorial and what are you using? Maybe the tutorial environment has a bunch of admin cmdlets via RSAT?

Comment: We both use Windows 7, I have installed 1:1 the same version of PowerShell as he did. He gets a list of about 12 commands, my list contains 2. I think it has something to do with the import of modules, but I'm quite confused since he never told something about that till now in the tutorial.

Comment: Powershell 3.0 automatically imports modules and has a lot more commands available than 2.0 in which you need to manually import modules, so answers will differ depending on your version of PowerShell. So again, what version do you have?

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel Major: 5  Minor: 0  Build: 10586  Revision: 117 information from `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't have all the help files downloaded to your computer.  Check out the Update-Help cmdlet, documented here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help